# iOS add UIButton from code: can't control UIButton titlebar text alignment

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have added a `UIButton` in a `UIView`,

```
    UIButton *switchButtonL = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeSystem];
    [switchButtonL addTarget:self action:@selector(switchCity:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    switchButtonL.frame =  CGRectMake(0, 50, self.screenWidth/2, 30);
    [switchButtonL setTitle: NSLocalizedString(@"switchcity", nil) forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [switchButtonL setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [switchButtonL setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [switchButtonL setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor] ];
    switchButtonL.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft; // this line can't work
    switchButtonL.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:18];
    [self addSubview:switchButtonL];
```

and the comment line can't work, the text align center always.

Comment: If any answer is relevant to u,plz make the tickmark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try substitute

```
switchButtonL.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft; // this line can't work
```

With:

```
switchButtonL.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
switchButtonL.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You can change it from xib shown in the above image. And if you want to change it by code use this with your required position:

```
self.yourbtn.titleEdgeInsets=UIEdgeInsetsMake(topVal, leftVal, downVal, rightVal);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
switchButtonL.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
switchButtonL.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 10, 0, 0);
```